# Composition of non-differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Is there example of two real functions $f$ and $g$  such that:
$g$ has a local minimum at $x=0$ ($g$ is not necessarily differentiable at $x=0$), 
$f\circ g$ is differentiable at 
$x=0$ but $(f\circ g)'(0)\neq 0$, and $f$  is differentiable at $g(0)$?

Comment: $g$ would have to be non-differentiable at $0$. Otherwise $(f\circ g)^{\prime}(0) = f^{\prime}(g(0))\cdot g^{\prime}(0) = 0$ since $g$ has a local minimum at $0$.

Comment: $g$ can be even discontinuos and the local min point $x=0$ can be an end-point of the domain.

Answer (score 3):

Sure -- let $f(x)=x(x+1)$ and
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & x=0 \\
                        x & x \ne 0 \end{cases} $$

It gets more difficult if you want $g$ to be continuous.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Makholm! Of course we restrict g to the interval $(-2\pi,\infty)$.

Comment: (Sorry, just rewrote it to a polynomial instead of a sine). You don't need to restrict $g$, since it was only specified that it had a _local_ minimum. But if you want a global minimum, just take the $x\ne 0$ branch of $g$ to be $|x+\frac12|-\frac12$ instead.

Comment: I liked the other example better and I am going to use it.

Comment: What to you need it for, anyway?

Comment: I am writing a paper about the derivative notion.I wanted to invalidate the chain rule under certain assumptions. Thank you again!